# Usage of "the" and omission of "the"

Tags: grammar

If I don't use the in the following sentences, would that be ungrammatical?

- (**The**) students in this school are very smart.
- (**The**) people in this town are very frankly.

Comment: The use of the article **the** is optional in these cases but the use of **frankly** in this context is decidedly puzzling.  Do you mean **honest**?

Comment: Yes I mean "honest".

Answer (score 1):

In both of these cases, you could omit the "the." It should be noted, however, that the second sentence is incorrect for another reason; frankly is an adverb (as are most words ending -ly). Here it is being used as an adjective; you probably want to say "People in this town are very frank."